# Facing read ECONNRESET in Perfecto execution

Tags: node.js, android-testing, webdriver-io, econnreset, perfecto

**While executing test script of android in Perfecto. Facing the below issue can anybody help with the solution. And the issue is coming randomly.
Stuffs used for execution - Webdriver-IO, Cucumber and Nodejs
**

```
RequestError: read ECONNRESET
at ClientRequest.\<anonymous\> (C:\\Perfecto Execution\\node_modules\\got\\dist\\source\\core\\index.js:956:111)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:\\Perfecto Execution\\node_modules@szmarczak\\http-timer\\dist\\source\\index.js:43:20)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:\_http_client:494:9)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
\[0-0\] Language Dropdown is Displayed.....
\[0-0\] node:internal/process/promises:288
\[0-0\]             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /\* fromPromise \*/);
\[0-0\]             ^
\[0-0\]
\[0-0\] RequestError: read ECONNRESET
\[0-0\]     at ClientRequest.\<anonymous\> (C:\\Perfecto Execution\\node_modules\\got\\dist\\source\\core\\index.js:956:111)
\[0-0\]     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
\[0-0\]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
\[0-0\]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
\[0-0\]     at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:\\Perfecto Execution\\node_modules@szmarczak\\http-timer\\dist\\source\\index.js:43:20)
\[0-0\]     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:\_http_client:494:9)
\[0-0\]     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
\[0-0\]     at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
\[0-0\]     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
\[0-0\]     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
\[0-0\]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
\[0-0\]     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
\[0-0\]   code: 'ECONNRESET',
\[0-0\]   timings: {
\[0-0\]     start: 1709120212552,
\[0-0\]     socket: 1709120212552,
\[0-0\]     lookup: 1709120212559,
\[0-0\]     connect: 1709120213279,
\[0-0\]     secureConnect: undefined,
\[0-0\]     upload: 1709120213279,
\[0-0\]     response: undefined,
\[0-0\]     end: undefined,
\[0-0\]     error: 1709120224509,
\[0-0\]     abort: undefined,
\[0-0\]     phases: {
\[0-0\]       wait: 0,
\[0-0\]       dns: 7,
\[0-0\]       tcp: 720,
\[0-0\]       tls: undefined,
\[0-0\]       request: 0,
\[0-0\]       firstByte: undefined,
\[0-0\]       download: undefined,
\[0-0\]       total: 11957
\[0-0\]     }
\[0-0\]   }
\[0-0\] Node.js v18.12.1
```

**Tried Changing the network but issue still persist.**